# GAE cannot Deploy to App Engine

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I'm trying to publish a web application from Eclipse. I have four projects created on GAE which I can see by logging into my account and viewing my console.

I have changed the `appengine-web.xml` to the application ID of the project.

If I change it to the first created project on GAE it works, I can deploy succesfully and see that my app is working online.

If I change the `appengine-web.xml` to another project ID which I created later it refuses to upload from eclipse and I get an error:

> The Project ID you selected, firstproject-dd, does not exist. Go to
>   http://cloud.google.com/console to view existing Project IDs or create
>   a new Project ID.
>
> Unable to update app: Error posting to URL:
>   https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=firstproject-dd&version=1&
>   404 Not Found This application does not exist
>   (project_id=u'firstproject-dd'). To create an App Engine application
>   in this project, run "gcloud beta app create" in your console.

I am running the free version of GAE (paid for nothing)

Comment: I am facing the same problem from python.

Answer (score 9):

You have to run this command `gcloud app create` in your **Google Cloud Shell** (see image below)  from **Google Developer Console**

[image]

App Engine is no longer automatically initialized for newly created projects, you must run this command on a newly created project before deploying on App Engine for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

First obvious step is to go to this page,

https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector/appengine

the second step is to select the project to which you need to create App engine application

the third step is to open the console and run the below command

> gcloud app create

This will create an App Engine application for you.

You can see the result of the command here,

> Creating App Engine application in project [sample-167809] and region [europe-west2]....done.
>   Success! The app is now created. Please use `gcloud app deploy` to deploy your first app.

After all the steps are successful, if you can try to deploy to App Engine.