# I am trying to deploy my project to Google app engine but I'm getting an error message

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to deploy my project to Google appengine. I get error message as shown below.
Project name: `u3eproject`
Project ID : `uthreee3`

Here is my `Appengine-web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
 <application>uthreee3</application>
 <version>1</version>

  <!--
    Allows App Engine to send multiple requests to one instance in parallel:
  -->
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

  <!-- Configure java.util.logging -->
  <system-properties>
  <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEBINF/logging.properties"/>
  </system-properties>

  <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>

</appengine-web-app>
```

This is the error message created.

```
C:\Users\u3e\web>e:\appengine\bin\appcfg.cmd update war
Sep 08, 2017 5:08:14 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
********************************************************
There is a new version of the SDK available.
-----------
Latest SDK:
Release: 1.9.55
Timestamp: Wed Aug 30 15:42:17 CDT 2017
API versions: [1.0]

-----------
Your SDK:
Release: 1.9.54
Timestamp: Mon Jun 05 17:56:09 CDT 2017
API versions: [1.0]

-----------
Please visit https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads for the latest SDK.
********************************************************
Reading application configuration data...
Sep 08, 2017 5:08:22 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.IndexesXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed war\WEB-INF/datastore-indexes.xml

Beginning interaction for module default...
Sep 08, 2017 5:08:22 PM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection send1
WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=uthreee3&version=1&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (project_id=u'uthreee3'). To create an App Engine application in this project, run "gcloud app create" in your console.
This is try #0
Sep 08, 2017 5:08:22 PM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection send1
WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=uthreee3&version=1&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (project_id=u'uthreee3'). To create an App Engine application in this project, run "gcloud app create" in your console.
This is try #1
Sep 08, 2017 5:08:23 PM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection send1
WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=uthreee3&version=1&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (project_id=u'uthreee3'). To create an App Engine application in this project, run "gcloud app create" in your console.
This is try #2
Sep 08, 2017 5:08:23 PM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection send1
WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=uthreee3&version=1&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (project_id=u'uthreee3'). To create an App Engine application in this project, run "gcloud app create" in your console.
This is try #3
0% Created staging directory at: 'C:\Users\avila\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg3268270747134041658.tmp'
5% Scanning for jsp files.
8% Generated git repository information file.
20% Scanning files on local disk.
25% Initiating update.
Sep 08, 2017 5:08:40 PM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection send1
WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=uthreee3&version=1&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (project_id=u'uthreee3'). To create an App Engine application in this project, run "gcloud app create" in your console.
This is try #0
Sep 08, 2017 5:08:41 PM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection send1
WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=uthreee3&version=1&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (project_id=u'uthreee3'). To create an App Engine application in this project, run "gcloud app create" in your console.
This is try #1
Sep 08, 2017 5:08:41 PM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection send1
WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=uthreee3&version=1&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (project_id=u'uthreee3'). To create an App Engine application in this project, run "gcloud app create" in your console.
This is try #2
Sep 08, 2017 5:08:41 PM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection send1
WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=uthreee3&version=1&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (project_id=u'uthreee3'). To create an App Engine application in this project, run "gcloud app create" in your console.
This is try #3

com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=uthreee3&version=1&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (project_id=u'uthreee3'). To create an App Engine application in this project, run "gcloud app create" in your console.

Unable to update app: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=uthreee3&version=1&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (project_id=u'uthreee3'). To create an App Engine application in this project, run "gcloud app create" in your console.
```

[I show the project exists in Google Appengine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3CsW.png)

Comment: That shows that a GCP project exists, but did you create a GAE app in it? Can you show the GAE app settings?

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41541873/3157062). Have you followed those steps?

Comment: Excellent, thanks it works now @ Parag jadhav